# How connect a signal declared in QML to a C++ method or lambda

Tags: qt, qml, signals-slots, qt5.15

I have Rectangle declared in QML like below:

```
Rectangle {
        objectName: "myquickitemobject"
        signal doSomething
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: { 
                doSomething() 
            }
        }
    }
```

I can get the QQuickItem object of `myquickitemobject` into C++ like below

```
// main.cpp
QQuickItem *my_quickitem = m_qml_item_root->findChild<QQuickItem*>("myquickitemobject");
```

**Question:**
How do I connect `signal doSomething` decalred in QML to a function or a lambda in C++?
Trying to do something like below which doesn't work..

```
QObject::connect(my_quickitem, doSomething, []{
    std::cout << "Signal doSomething called" << std::endl;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare a Slot like below in your class:

```
Q_SLOT void DoSomething() {
    std::cout << "Do something" << std::endl;
}
```

And then connect them like below:

```
QQuickItem *my_quickitem = m_qml_item_root->findChild<QQuickItem*>("myquickitemobject");
QObject::connect(my_quickitem, SIGNAL(doSomething()), this, SLOT(DoSomething()));
```